# Jquery ajax wrong data response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

It looks like that i got wrong type or something going on

```
function updateCart()
{
var dataArray= [];
 var  i=0;
 var item;
$('.cd-cart .wrapper .body .product').each(function()
{
  var item=new Array();
  i++;
  var $element = $(this)
  qty=parseInt($element.find('select').val());
  name=$element.find('h3 a').html();
  price=parseInt($element.find('.price1').text().replace('₽',''));
  id=parseInt($element.attr('id').replace('product_',''));
  image=$element.find('img')[0].src;
item['id']=id;
  item['price']=price;
  item['name']=name;
  item['qty']=qty;
  item['image']=image;

  dataArray.push(item);
});
var jObject={};
jObject = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
$.ajax({
    url: '/updateCart',
    type: 'get',
    dataType:'json',
     data: ({dataArray:jObject}),
success:function(data){
          console.log(data);
      },
      error:function(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
}); 
}
```

Server-side got return $_GET;
I got this response from the server :Object {dataArray: "[[],[]]"}
What can i do to get Normal response?
P.S dataArray is an array of an array

Comment: I think I can see the issue here, but for debugging purposes since we know your server is getting the request and sending back what it sees as a response you can probably comment out your AJAX call and just try printing the dataArray to the console. Make sure you are sending what you think you are is always my first step with javascript :).

Comment: @DLowther This is how array looks like with some data [Array[0]] 0: Array[0] id: 9 image: "items/2ktXCd2j1488052733.jpg" name: "Free" price: 123 qty: 2
After JSON.stringify i got : [[]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some reformatting here while I was trying to run down your codes flow. Generally if you need an associative array style grouping in JavaScript you want to use an object, not an array. Arrays are indexed, Objects keyed. In my example I used a constructor function to build your item. You could also `let data = {};` and then build the keys like `data.id = 1`.

```
// formatted for readability.
function updateCart() {
  const data = buildCart();
  let dataObj = JSON.stringify(data)
  makeRequest('/updateCart', dataObj);
}

function buildCart() {
  let data = [];

  $('.cd-cart .wrapper .body .product').each(function() {
    const $element = $(this);
    let qty = parseInt($element.find('select').val())
     ,  name = $element.find('h3 a').html()
     ,  price = parseInt($element.find('.price1').text().replace('₽',''))
     ,  id = parseInt($element.attr('id').replace('product_',''))
     ,  image = $element.find('img')[0].src;

    data.push(new Item(id, price, name, qty, image));
  });

  return data;
}

function Item(id, price, name, qty, image) 
{
  this.id = id
  this.price = price;
  this.name = name;
  this.qty = qty;
  this.image = image;
}

function makeRequest(url, dataObj) 
{
  let token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  let jqXHR = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    headers: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token,
    dataType: 'json',
    jsonp: false,
    data: {dataArray: dataObj}
  });

  jqXHR.done(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
    // success
  });

  jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) {
    // failure
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot.Before this I spent 1.5 hours on this and didn`t come to the solution.